# Unable to Start Subversion on windows 2003 server. StartService FAILED 1053

Tags: svn, windows-server-2003

good peeps of the world, I'm in the process of migrating from VSS to SVN (all these days of futile versioning ...)

anyway i've come to the point of creating the service, i used the following command:

```
sc create svn_hr binpath= "\"c:\program files\subversion\bin\svnserve.exe\" --service -rd:\SVN\SVN_HR" displayname= "Subversion Server" depend= Tcpip start= auto
```

This successfully creates the SVN service:

> [SC] CreateService SUCCESS

I now try to run the service like so:

```
sc start SVN_HR
```

This returns an error for me:

> sc start SVN_HR
>
> [SC] StartService FAILED 1053:
>
> The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

I did some googling around and have arrived at the conclusion that there's something wrong with my rights permission or the service is not coming up because of some rights issue. Could anyone help me out with this? I'm presuming this is a basic problem faced... ?

I've installed Subversion 1.6.6 on Windows Server 2003 standard edition.

kindly enlighten the noob!

Cheers
K

Comment: any changes to the config file?

Comment: Yup i added a couple of changes but the very basic ones.. In svnserve.conf
    [general]
    # anon-access = read
    auth-access = write
    password-db = passwd
    realm = HrDev

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to run the command line you're passing to `sc`?

ie: can you execute: `"c:\program files\subversion\bin\svnserve.exe\" --service -rd:\SVN\SVN_HR`

I think I'm a couple minor versions behind, but unless you have a typo, "-rd" isn't an option to svnserve. -r and --root are, however.

Comment: @Yoopergeek, I think its just a missed out space between -r d:\SVN\SVN_HR. Unless it is a typo in the post, I think you are right about that being the possible cause. 

@Kaushik. The successful creation of service does not mean it will be able to find the correct binary in the right path or has the right permission. So you may want to look at any possible typos.If its all ok, then I think it is because you need admin previleges in some windows versions in order to get the service up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Check under what ID the service runs, and if that user have all the access it needs to the service files/ repositories.

You can make the service run under system permissions, which will make it maybe too strong but if you are not to deal with security issues, it might help solving the problem.

did you check the eventvwr for errors ?

Comment: Hey Dani really appreciate the help, but you're dealing with a complete noob here, any ideas how to identify the service id ? 

I tried going into the Manage Services area, i don't see my service listed there at all, but i know for sure the service has been created. Am i looking in the right place? is there a simpler way to go about this process of finding my service?

Comment: If you are a self-described "complete noob" I would strongly recommend you take a look at one of the packaged "all in one" installers.  Collabnet ships one, VisualSVN has one as well - both free.  They have an installer that will configure svnserve as a service for you.

Comment: :). I tried the same process on a pc hosted in the company network and everything worked fine. I followed a similar process of installation on the server but got the described error. So i presume it isn't an issue with my methodology of installation but rather something that's different on the server environment (After googling around I came across VisualSVN as well but facing the same issue...simply doesn't recognize the service).I strongly feel it's just a question of identifying and starting the service process for svn or the svn daeomon....? don't know where to start looking :(

Comment: Did you check in start->Settings->control panel->administrative tools-> services
there if you find your service double click on it, and check the logon tab. if you change it to local system account it might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Good peeps...

many thanks for the support.

As Dani, Critical Skill & Yoopergeek have rightly suggested it's an issue with admin privileges. I searched for the svnserve.exe file, right clicked the file -> compatibility and checked the "Allow NonAdministrators to run this program". I deleted and re-created everything and now it's seems to be going through fine.

I doubt this is going to be a major security threat etc..

@Yoopergeek the -rD isn't actually a typo the service gets created correctly, while it's true the argument is -r only the D is from the location of the file i.e D:\SVN\SVN_HR. Apparently the space in between is not mandatory